# Word for Self-Exemplifying Phrase

Tags: single-word-requests, literary-techniques, onomatopoeia, literary-device

Depeche Mode's song, "I Promise You I Will," contains the following lines:

> I'm sorry, but I'm just thinking of the right words to say
>
> (I promise you)
>
> **I know they don't sound the way I planned them to be**

The third line, I assume, is intentionally poorly-worded to exemplify the artist's failure to speak eloquently; his awkwardly-worded sentence obviously does not "sound the way [he] planned" it to sound.

For general English usage, is there a word that describes this type of literary device, in which a word or phrase is descriptive and/or exemplary of itself?

The closest term I can think of is onomatopoeia, but it only applies to individual words, not phrases, sentences, or even entire bodies of meta-writing.

Comment: They're [**performative** verbs/statements](http://poligo.com/articles/grammar/performative-verbs-when-you-say-word-you-do-action-word-describes) - *when you say [something] you do the action the word[s] describe*.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of _self-referential_? E.g. _terse_ is a word that can refer to itself.

Comment: If the canon and I were one and the same, I'd call it "*a turn of phrase*."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A word or phrase that "expresses a property that it also possesses" is called ***autological***, ***homological***, or ***autonymic*** ([here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word)).

A canonical example is the word 'polysyllabic', which both expresses the property of being polysyllabic and also *is* polysyllabic.

There is nothing barring the application of the concept to phrases and whole sentences.

Answer (score 0):

**Self-descriptive**, because it's immediately obvious what that means. As a side note, "self-descriptive" is self-descriptive. Note that it's not a real word, sadly.

[Self-referential](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/self-referential) and [performative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/performative) might work, as suggested in the comments, but neither is really accurate.

Comment: I would up-vote your answer if you shortened it to **"I think the best word is "self-descriptive," because it is immediately obvious what that means."** :-)

Comment: @MarkHubbard I kept in the other words because IMO closely related words are useful too.

Answer (score -1):

We may use the words 'SELF-EVIDENT' or 'AXIOMATICAL' which mean obviously true and requiring no proof, argument or explanation that is to say SELF-EXPLANATORY.