# Is there term for a list which is an example of itself? (similar to autological for a single word)

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I have a bulleted list which describes how to write an effective bulleted list, and is itself an example of all the tips in the list.

Terms in this area that I have found so far are:

- autological / homological
- self-referential
- recursive

Is one of these best, or is there another term (single word or phrase) that I can use to describe this list? e.g. The ____ list above is...

Comment: I'd say ***self-referential*** only really works if the text *explicitly* refers to itself as being an example of what it's talking about. If not, I might go for [***self-exemplifying***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22self-exemplifying%22). Or ***self-descriptive*** if I thought whoever I was talking to might not understand ***exemplify***.

Comment: See [Word for Self-Exemplifying Phrase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275251/word-for-self-exemplifying-phrase)

Comment: _Self-referential_ is fine; the broader meaning is 'relating [in a reasonably obvious way] to itself/oneself'. However, I'd use 'The list above (which you'll notice is self-referential) ...' unless self-reference was the salient point.

Comment: [autological](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/autological) probably - Wiktionary says it can apply to phrases and words, but it can probably be extended to longer texts.

Answer (score 2):

That would be a ***meta-list***:

> **meta**
>  <sub>adjective</sub>
>
> **(of something that is written or performed) referring to itself or to something of its own type:**
>  <sub>• *It’s a meta joke. It’s
> sort of a joke about jokes.*</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: (Cambridge Dictionary —
> *meta*)[https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/meta]</sub>